# Как вывести jqvmap в полноэкранное модальное окно?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть проект в котором необходимо интерактивно использовать выбор страны, наткнулся на компонент - **jqvmap** который собственно позволяет отобразить карту и получить код страны в формате ISO...

Каким образом эту карту можно отобразить в модальном окне?

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
          map: 'world_en',
          backgroundColor: '#333333',
          color: '#ffffff',
          hoverOpacity: 0.7,
          selectedColor: '#666666',
          enableZoom: true,
          showTooltip: true,
          scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
          values: sample_data,
          normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        });
jQuery(".openMap").click(function(){
  $("#vmap").show(function(){
   $("#vmap").addClass("show");
  });
 });

      });
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#vmap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
 /*background-color: red;*/
 display:none;
}
.show{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://semenov.ru.com/dist/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://semenov.ru.com/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://semenov.ru.com/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
<script src="http://semenov.ru.com/dist/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="openMap">Open</a>
 <p>Какой то текст</p>
 <p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p><p>Какой то текст</p>
<div id="vmap"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

Comment: Тут не совсем то что искал, вообще задумка - есть кнопка при нажатии которой всплывает окно с картой в полноэкраном модальном окне...

Comment: Наверное я не совсем корректно выразился в первый раз - развернуть необходимо карту на полный экран в окне браузера а не монитора...

Comment: `position: fixed` и четыре нолика.

Comment: Даже при условии что я при открытии окна делаю fixed окно, оно во первых прокручивается, во вторых стиль при появлении окна выставляет relative... - обновил код.